# Java code 1+ issue

Tags: java, arrays, random, int

problem with Java code.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class arrayTable {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Index\t + Value");
    int Array[] = new int[10];

    Random Object = new Random();
    int Values;

    // Assigning random values to each element of array

    for(int i=0; i<Array.length;i++) {
        Values= (1+Object.nextInt(50));
        Array[i] = Values;
    }

    for(int j=0;j<Array.length;j++) {
        System.out.println(j + "\t" + Array[j]);
      }

    }
}
```

Here with this code i wrote (1+) next to the object so the index should start at 1, however when ever i run the code at always starts at index 0, and it does not matter if i type 2+ or 3+ pr whatever. Could anyone be helpful with pointing out the problem with the code.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Take care of the Java naming convention. Class names should start with upper case letter, variable names with lower Case letter

Comment: What's the problem? The values you are storing in your array are all bigger or equal to 1.

Comment: What means *so the index should start at 1,*? The index is i and starts as defined in the loop at 0

Comment: Also note: http://i.imgur.com/U6hU1Ac.jpg

Comment: i'm very aware, that all arrays starts at 0 lol, but i want the index to count from 1 and up, and i believe i added the 1+ the wrong place. And i actully did not know classes should always start with upper case letters and vice versa for varibles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i wrote (1+) next to the object so the index should start at 1

You wrote 1+ next to the **value** not the **index**!

So, what you were doing was:

```
array[0] = 50 + 1;
```

Instead of:

```
array[0 + 1] = 50;
```

If you wanted to start from index 1 you should write it here:

```
Array[i + 1] = Values;
```

However as you're inside a `for` loop, you could run into an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so, a better idea would be:

```
for(int i=1; i<Array.length;i++) { //Look the "i" was initialized with 1 and not with 0.
```

**REMEMBER**: ARRAYS START FROM `0` INDEX

If you want to "skip" the first element, then the above modification to `for` loop should work, but if you want it to run from `1` to `10` then it's a bad idea, because it should be from `0` to `9`

You should also be careful to follow the Java naming conventions:

- `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`
- `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`
- `FirstWordUpperCaseClass`
- `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`

and use them consistently, this will make your code easier to read and understand for you and for us.

Also, try not to name your classes / variables as Java classes names:

`Object` or `Array` or `List`, etc might be wrong choices, also having `object` lowercase would be a bad idea as it's not descriptive either as suggested by @nicomp on the comments below

---

> but when i type Array [i + 1] it still prints out from index 0, if for example i where to make i dice i would want it to start at index 1, is there no way to do this?

I think you didn't changed the `for(int j=0;j<Array.length;j++) {` loop, to start from `1`

To make a dice I would:

- Create the array with 6 slots (starting from 0)
- Fill it (1 - 6) like below (inside a `for` loop):

  ```
  dice[0] = 1;
  dice[1] = 2;
  ...
  dice[5] = 6;

  //Example of for loop
  for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
      dice[i] = i + 1;
  }
  ```
- Get a random number (between 0 - 5) called `random`
- Get the value of the array at position `random`

For example:

```
random = 3;
//dice[random] = 4;
System.out.println(dice[random]);
```

Comment: If we are piling on, let's not name an object 'Object' or even 'object.'

Comment: but when i type  Array [i + 1] it still prints out from index 0, if for example i where to make i dice i would want it to start at index 1, is there no way to do this?

Comment: @Frakcool I am kept awake at night by the Object class in Java. Makes me crazy.

Comment: @nicomp take care, it told me it was gonna haunt you tonight!